# String.split() is not working

Tags: java, android

I have to split a string in this way :

```
String s = "00JS1B4BJG2C2G3S6C6S5CHG1C4CKS3C1G5S6B3G7BHB7G6G5B";
String[] result = s.substring(2).split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
```

The correct result is:

```
["JS","1B","4B","JG","2C","2G","3S","6C","6S","5C","HG","1C","4C","KS","3C","1G","5S","6B","3G","7B","HB","7G","6G","5B"]
```

And this is working in Java, but in Android it returns:

```
["JS", "1B4BJG2C2G3S6C6S5CHG1C4CKS3C1G5S6B3G7BHB7G6G5B"]
```

...as I can see when debugging:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: If I had to guess, some regex rule changed in newer versions of Java, where Android maintained the old behavior for backwards-compatibility reasons. I'm not sure that there is anything that you can do about this, other than to come up with another parsing algorithm.

Comment: try this `String[] result = s.substring(2).replaceAll("(.{2})", "$1-").split("-");`
The idea is to put a separator after each two characters, the split with this separator, in my case I used hyphen (-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I had put the OP's original (shorter) code into an Android project and a plain Java project and reproduced the findings. There's definitely a difference in behavior between Java 8 on Ubuntu and Android 7.1.1, the two environments that I tried.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yeah, and if the workaround in Arash's answer fixes it, then it's not the zero-width space issue I'm remembering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this expression ( `G..` instead of `G.{2}` ):

```
s.split("(?<=\\G..)")
```

Or you can appending space every two step ( using as delimiter ) :

```
s = s.replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0 ");
s.split(" ");
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? Why did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers.

Comment: And? `.{2}` and `..` are identical in effect, and you've ignored the other questions.

Comment: what about second way ? @Fr4ncx

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: There's also no need for the `(?!$)` at the end.